# How can I create or upload plain text file on blogger like these two URLs?

Tags: text, upload, blogger

How can I create or upload plain text file on blogger like these two URLs?

[crimlaw.blogspot.com/Resume.txt](http://crimlaw.blogspot.com/Resume.txt)
and
[crimlaw.blogspot.com/smith appellee.txt](http://crimlaw.blogspot.com/smith%20appellee.txt)

Comment: It is not possible to upload files other than image and video files to Blogger. So, how those two text files stand there?

Comment: Something like this is not possible to do via the current Blogger interface. As this blog is quite old (operating since the early 2000s), it's likely that older versions of Blogger provided this feature. Upon checking, this blog does have several differences from a normal Blogger blog (like URL structure for archive pages - http://crimlaw.blogspot.com/archives/2004_03_01_crimlaw_archive.html . I couldn't locate any official source which could prove that such a feature existed in older versions, therefore started a bounty on the question if someone knows more about this.

Comment: @PrayagVerma thanks for your answer.

http://www.blogger.com/blog-publishing.g?blogID=XXXXXXXX&publishMode=PUBLISH_MODE_FTP

Comment: @PrayagVerma You're right, I wrote something about that.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger had FTP support lets you to publish posts on your own ftp space until May 1, 2010.

In those days, when you create a post, Blogger engine compile your entire blog to hundreds of html files and assets to upload your FTP space.

Those text files must be surviving ones from the final migration which has an official blog still accessible at http://blogger-ftp.blogspot.com/