# How do I SSH (or FTP) into a Blogger host?

Tags: ssh, blogger

I know this is possible because I've done it before, but I can't seem to find any information on it.

Comment: You may confuse blogger with another blogging service.

Comment: That was possible to do till 2010. FTP support has been discontinued since then. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085638/how-can-i-create-or-upload-plain-text-file-on-blogger-like-these-two-urls/44189095#44189095 and http://blogger-ftp.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Blogger is hosted on Google's own cloud infrastructure. They do not supply any ssh/scp/ftp interface.